# android pop up menus

Tags: android, menu, popup

I cannot find either one of these two views in the source, but have seen them both in many apps.  Can anyone please tell me what they are called?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second one is an options menu from the action bar. I think it is implemented as a `ListPopupWindow`.

The first one is not part of the Android SDK, though there are various implementations floating around. [Here is an example of one](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) designed for use with Google Maps, for example. [Here is one](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) designed for the "quick actions" pattern.

Comment: I had a hunch the ListPopupWindow was a newer API than I can build with.. oh well.  The source for those balloons will do great though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that they're custom made ones, so you won't find them in the standard Android libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The second one I think is just the way that the default menu looks in ICS (and honeycomb for that matter). If you build for 4.0 and include the code for an options menu I think you'll get that UI by default. If you are looking to customize it check out this page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html and pay close attention to the "Adding drop down navigation" section.

The first one is not a part of the android UI, that is something specific to the facebook app.