# Android popup menu - back button and options

Tags: android, menu, popup, popupwindow

I'm currently trying to get my popup window to have a back button on its top left, followed by a title, and to the right I'd like to have a ListPopupWindow (as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595716/android-pop-up-menus))
I would be able to "build" this view manually, however I believe there must be a way to do this with some help (I'm not fond of reinventing the wheel).
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: There does not seem to be a real question :) First off, the back arrow in the upper left is not the Android way. Usually, the user can get this popup closed by tipping outside of the popup or by pressing the back button. If you have to create that arrow just call the onBackPressed method in the click handler.

Comment: My bad, I should've specified that this is an "inner list", if you click the back button it goes back to a more general section (for example thats the list of books of an author, if I click the back button I'd go to the "authors list")

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewname, null);
builder.setView(view);

TextView title = new TextView(this);
// You Can Customise your Title here 
title.setText("Custom Centered Title");
title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
title.setTextSize(20);
title.setonclicklistner(new onclicklistner()
{
@ovrried
onclick(view v)
{

 }

   })
builder.setCustomTitle(title);
```

*create custum pop up and also creta custum, action bar in pop up u can do esaly if u can do custum pup up *